# GSUTIL CP command behavior inconsistency

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil, google-cloud-sdk

Few days ago when we tried executing a command like below

gsutil cp gs://test_buckt_source/test_folder_source/test_file.txt gs://test_buckt_target/test_folder_target/

It used to create the test_folder_target  folder in test_buckt_target  bucket without copying the file test_file.txt.

Today it is copying the file. Is this due to the difference in gsutil version . Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Its going to be hard to say what might have happened given that the situation now is what I would have expected it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was a bug with v4.43 that was fixed recently:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/pull/905

v4.44 is doing the correct thing by creating the file.

Comment: Thanks this helps !